# How can I create a public function to show the indexPath of a selected cell in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my application I need a public function / public var in which I need to know the `indexPath` of a selected cell. Since Im a new coder I have some ideas how to make it but none of them has worked yet.

I just want, that I can access the selected indexPath from everywhere in the class. So I need some advice/help.

```swift
 func selectedColor(){
    let cell = gamePad.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "coloredCell", for: IndexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        let selectedCell = gamePad.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint)
    }
```

Comment: Instead of blatantly stating that you have tried something, but it didn't work, you should actually [edit] your question and include the code you tried, even if it didn't work. People will be much more helpful if they see some effort from your side and it can be more helpful for you as well to get your own code corrected rather than be given a large piece of code written from scratch.

Comment: Since you are new to coding let me explain that there is rarely a reason to maintain that kind of information in a public variable! You should give the variables only the amount of scope they really need--and global is very very rare.

Comment: @Barns Ok, thank you. How should I than look, which cell is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Dávid Pásztor, but help you for first time. You need implement delegate of UITableView. I think it's will be look like this:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension TableViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}
```

P.S. For UICollectionView it is same, but you need implement UICollectionViewDelegate and look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}
```

P.S. If you don't need to know a moment when cell was tapped, then you can use [indexPathForSelectedRow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow) (@rmaddy)

Comment: None of this is needed. Both UICollectionView and UITableView already provide a property to get the currently selected index paths.

Answer (score -1):

`indexPathsForSelectedItems` on UICollectionView

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618099-indexpathsforselecteditems

Comment: Im doing it with a UICollectionView so there solutions won't work I think